# Blazor WASM exception leads to hundreds of additional socket and connection exceptions

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I just started to learn Blazor WASM (normally I'm a backend developer), and I'm confused about something I'm seeing happening quite frequently.

This is probably a very noob question, but please bear with me.

#### Why is that Blazor often keeps endlessly throwing exceptions?

It starts with a concrete exception like this, and this much I still understand (obviously as a complete Blazor rookie I have no idea what I'm doing; but the only relevant part is that an exception is being thrown):

```csharp
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputNumber`1[System.Int32] requires a cascading parameter of type EditContext. For example, you can use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputNumber`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]] inside an EditForm.
System.InvalidOperationException: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputNumber`1[System.Int32] requires a cascading parameter of type EditContext. For example, you can use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputNumber`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]] inside an EditForm.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputBase`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SetDirectParameters(ParameterView parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 newFrameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer renderer, RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, Int32 componentId, ArrayRange`1 oldTree, ArrayRange`1 newTree)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
```

But then this happens, and it just goes on and on:

```csharp
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Net.Security.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Net.Security.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Net.Security.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Net.Security.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Net.Security.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Net.Security.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Net.Security.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Net.Security.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Net.Security.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Net.Security.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Net.Security.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Net.Security.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Net.Security.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Net.Security.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Net.Security.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Net.Security.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Net.Security.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Net.Security.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Net.Security.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Net.Security.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Net.Security.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

And trust me, I only copied around 15% of the debug log.

Also, it seems it's bogging down a lot of threads while doing so, as the debug log ends like this:

```csharp
The thread 0x3b00 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x9e68 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xabbc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x23d4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x6690 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4934 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x976c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xb908 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x50a0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xb1bc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xcc5c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x79b4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x9bd4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x6980 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x9c98 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xbb90 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x51f0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x79f4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x671c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xcac4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5b8c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xab64 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x6710 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x7814 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x97dc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x35a0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xd430 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x9608 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xa85c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x15b0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xa284 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5fb4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xa288 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x529c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x9790 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x8ef8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2efc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x9854 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3e3c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x8e94 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

The component where the exception happened is dead simple. Basically I just started to experiment with some fields (as I noted, I have obviously no idea what I'm doing, but that's not relevant, unless it directly causes the torrent of above exceptions):

```razor
@page "/test"

<InputNumber TValue="int" ValueChanged="numberEntered"></InputNumber>

<p>The number you entered is: </p>

<InputText @ref="inputText"></InputText>

@code {
    InputText inputText;

    void numberEntered(int number)
    {
        inputText.Value = number.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running with `dotnet watch run` or Ctrl-F5 (if using VS2019)? The only time websockets are involved in Blazor WebAssembly is when the browser reload feature is running

Comment: @MisterMagoo yes, I'm running it from VS2019, in debug mode.

Comment: Ah right, so those websocket errors will be coming from the debugger connection then - which presumably isn't happy because the application has thrown an unhandled error - I would recommend not debugging a webassembly version - it works, but is known to be more of a pain than it should be. If you need to debug something, you can always use a Blazor Server project to debug it, you get a far better experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original error gives a pretty good indication of what went wrong:

> Unhandled exception rendering component: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputNumber`1[System.Int32] requires a cascading parameter of type EditContext. For example, you can use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputNumber`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]] inside an EditForm.

`InputNumber` is a built-in `number` type input that expects a `CascadingValue` of type `EditContext`. [Read Cascading Parameters and Values here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

If you don't care about validation, switch to using a simple `<input>`. Otherwise, you need a parent component to provide an `EditContext`: the [EditForm](http://crit:%20Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer%5B100%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Unhandled%20exception%20rendering%20component:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputNumber%601%5BSystem.Int32%5D%20requires%20a%20cascading%20parameter%20of%20type%20EditContext.%20For%20example,%20you%20can%20use%20Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputNumber%601%5B%5BSystem.Int32,%20System.Private.CoreLib,%20Version=5.0.0.0,%20Culture=neutral,%20PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e%5D%5D%20inside%20an%20EditForm.) is a built-in solution; start there.

Your subsequent errors (`Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException'`) are likely the debugger attempting to reconnect to your app but failing since your app has run into an unhandled exception (above) and ceased execution. Your debugger doesn't know why the connection is closed and will keep retrying the connection.

Comment: So essentially what I experienced with respect to the hundreds of exceptions is designed, expected behavior when debugging a WASM app that throws an exception?

Comment: I haven't used Blazor WASM, only server, but it looks like a tooling issue, not the project's: VS continuously trying to debug. That probably won't be anything you did in your code.

Comment: Okay then, I accepted your answer, since this contained an explanation of what is happening; I don't think we'll get anything better than this, since it indeed appears this is how the debugging is designed currently. Btw, I already started to use `EditForm` with proper models, validation, etc. ;) I'm actually not a slow learner; just that the code in the question was basically my very first try at using Blazor (and Razor).

Comment: Sorry, I realize I gave you more than what you asked for :)

Answer (score 8):

What fixed this for me was checking the "Enable Just My Code" box in the Options menu.

Debug -> Options -> General -> Enable Just My Code

Comment: Lifesaver!  Disabling Just My Code is handy to step into a source link package when debugging, but you've got to remember to re-enable Just My Code when you no longer need to do that!

Answer (score 3):

You "simple" piece of code breaks a few rules.

And I endorse what @MisterMagoo said.  Start with Server to make debugging easy.

1. Input control needs to be added inside an `EditForm` with a valid `EditContext` or `Model`
2. You should normally be binding a field or property to the control using `@bind-Value`, as shown below.  Read up about binding.
3. InputText.Value sets a parameter on a component - a nono.

Here's a version of your code that works:

```cs
<EditForm Model="model">
    <InputNumber TValue="int" @bind-Value="model.Value"></InputNumber>
</EditForm>

<div>@model.Value</div>
@code {

    Model model = new Model() { Value = 4 };

    class Model
    {
        public int Value { get; set; } = 0;
    }
}
```

Start using [MSDocs - Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) or another Blazor reference.  In my early days it was my bible.

Comment: Sure, I appreciate the response. What I wrote is what happens when a backend developer starts to use Blazor/Razor, haha. Although I'm actually not that bad with e.g. Angular. And meanwhile I did implement the structure you're suggesting. (I also ran into the problem if trying to use bind-value with small 'v' first.) Although obviously this won't answer the main question about the hundreds of socket and connection exceptions thrown. I found some github issues related to that, but with no resolution or further information.

Comment: These are mostly your preferences, not hard-fast rules.  `ValueChanged` is a valid method to handle input events. The way you phrased it makes it sound like this is the only way to do something in Blazor, which is not true.

Comment: @Leaky, sorry for the typos I was trying to do three things at once and failed!  And NP, but start with Blazor Server to get a feel for what your doing.  Not me.

Comment: @ConnorLow.  Not my intent but on re-reading maybe, so I've amended my answer.  I did say here's a version  Ta.